# Bootstrap dropdown font gets bigger after clicking

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I have really weird problem in my project. When I click bootstrap dropdown the font of button and menu gets really big. I validated my code yesterday and it did not show any errors. Here is my code and error

```
<li class="nav-item">
                        
    <div class="dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#"  id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Twój profil
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton" style="background: #eeeeee">
             <a class="dropdown-item" href="/user/<%= currentUser._id %>/edit">Edytuj informacje</a>
             <a class="dropdown-item" href="/user/<%= currentUser._id %>/edit/profile">Edytuj zdjęcie profilowe</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image: error]
[codepen](https://codepen.io/crazydeveloper09/pen/zYKVqyr)

Comment: Hi There ! This has to do with your custom CSS :-) If you could create a codepen link or add your CSS code as well. We will try to help you out :-D !!! This may also be a javascript code error :-) The problem can get clear only after looking at the full code

Comment: I added codepen link

Comment: Great :) Let me see ^^

Comment: Dear friend :-) It is resolved !!! Have a nice day

Comment: Thanks for resolving it :D have a nice day too

Comment: U r welcome Mate :) Cheers :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you are using a `show` class with size `40px;` and that's ultimately being applied on `dropdown.show`.

```
.show {
/* font-size: 40px;  Here is the problem*/
}
```

**CODEPEN LINK:** https://codepen.io/emmeiWhite/pen/VwKJjZr

**Full Working Code:**

```css
body,
html {
    background: #F2F4F5;
}

.bg-gradient {
    background: goldenrod;
}

#mainNav .nav-link {
    font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: white;
}

#mainNav .nav-link:hover {
    
    color: lightseagreen;
    border-bottom: 1px solid lightseagreen;
}

#mainNav .nav-link .active {
    color: lightseagreen;
    border-bottom: 1px solid lightseagreen;
}


#websiteName {
    color: goldenrod;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
}

#websiteInfo {
    color: lightseagreen;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.subpage-title {
    font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
    color: lightseagreen;
    font-weight: 700;
}
.card-title {
    
    font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
    color: goldenrod;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 700;
}

input[type=search] {
    border-color: lightseagreen;
    color: lightseagreen;
}

input[type=search]::placeholder {
    color: lightseagreen;
}
.btn-outline-mine {
    background: #fff;
    border-color: lightseagreen;
    border-left: none;
    color: lightseagreen;
}
.description {
    font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
a {
    color: #212529;
}
.text-green {
    color: lightseagreen;
    font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.button-small {
    background-color: lightseagreen;
    border-color: lightseagreen;
}

.author-city {
    font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
    color: lightsteelblue;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.price {
    font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.badge-mine {
    background: lightseagreen;
    border-color: lightseagreen;
}
.badge-golden {
    background: goldenrod;
    border-color: goldenrod;
}

.footer {
    font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
    color: lightseagreen;
    font-size: 14px;
} 

.footer a {
    color: lightseagreen;
}

.show {
/*     font-size: 40px; */
}
.footer-title {
    font-size: 30px;
}
.author-row {
    font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
    color: lightseagreen;
    font-weight: 700;
}
#user_id {
    opacity: 0;
}
#categories a,
#types a,
#announcementsUser a {
    font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
    font-size: 19px;
    color: #77a6f2;
}

.logo {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 100;
}

.text-mute {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
    color:lightseagreen;
}
```

```html
<html lang="pl">


<head>
    <title> crazydev09 dashboard | 5zeta </title>


    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/b2ec1cb26d.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css">



</head>

<body>
    
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-gradient justify-content-center" id="mainNav">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand logo" href="/">5zeta.pl</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" style="border:none;">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto text-center">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link active" href="/dashboard">Ogłoszenia</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="/announcements/new">Dodaj ogłoszenie</a>
                        </li>    
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            
                            <div class="dropdown">
                                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle justify-content-center" href="#"  id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                    Twój profil
                                </a>
                                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton" style="background: #eeeeee">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/user/600b1c7ef0f93f0998523a32/edit">Edytuj informacje</a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/user/600b1c7ef0f93f0998523a32/edit/profile">Edytuj zdjęcie profilowe</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                           
                        </li>
                        
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="/user">Użytkownicy</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="/announcements/category">kategorie</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="/announcements/type">typy</a>
                            </li>
                        
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="/logout">Wyloguj się</a>
                        </li>
                       
                    </ul>
                </div>  
            </div>      
        </nav>
    
   

<br>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h2 class="subpage-title text-center">
                
                    Ogłoszenia, które zostały dodane
                
              
               : 3
            </h2>
            <p class="description text-center">Zalogowany jako crazydev09</p>
            
        </div>
    </div>
    
        
            <div class="row">
                
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                        <div class="card">
                            <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/syberiancats/image/upload/v1611341251/r6gylsh84cz0xp5fvqwo.jpg" alt="zdjęcie ogłoszenia" class="card-img-top">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <div class="card-title">Pies rasowy Labrador</div>
                                <span class="badge text-light border border-success badge-mine">Moda i fitness v2</span>
                                
                                <p class="description">
                                    
                                        test ogłoszenia
                                    
                                
                                </p>
                                <div>
                                    <p class="float-left author-city"> Glogow</p>
                                    <p class="float-right price"> 700zł</p>
                                </div>
                                <div style="clear: both;">
                                    
                                        
                                            <div class="dropdown">
                                                <button class="btn button-small btn-success dropdown-toggle justify-content-center" type="button" id="dropdownMenu" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                                    Modyfikacja
                                                </button>
                                                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu" style="background: #eeeeee">
                                                    <a href="/announcements/600b1dc4f0f93f0998523a33/edit" class="dropdown-item">Edytuj</a>
                                                    <a href="/announcements/600b1dc4f0f93f0998523a33/delete" class="dropdown-item">Usuń</a>
                                                    <a href="/announcements/600b1dc4f0f93f0998523a33/add/picture" class="dropdown-item">Dodaj zdjęcie do galerii</a>
                                                    <a href="/announcements/600b1dc4f0f93f0998523a33/edit/picture" class="dropdown-item">
                                                        Edytuj zdjęcie główne
                                                    </a>
                                                    <a href="/announcements/pies-rasowy-labrador?announcement_id=600b1dc4f0f93f0998523a33" class="dropdown-item">Zobacz podgląd</a>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        
                                        
                                    
                                   
                                </div>
                               
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                        <div class="card">
                            <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/syberiancats/image/upload/v1611347882/cfkp3njer39p1zfite1d.jpg" alt="zdjęcie ogłoszenia" class="card-img-top">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <div class="card-title">Pisek</div>
                                <span class="badge text-light border border-success badge-mine">Moda i fitness v2</span>
                                
                                <p class="description">
                                    
                                        Do oddania bardzo fajny piesek
                                    
                                
                                </p>
                                <div>
                                    <p class="float-left author-city"> Głogów</p>
                                    <p class="float-right price"> 0zł</p>
                                </div>
                                <div style="clear: both;">
                                    
                                        
                                            <a href="/announcements/pisek?announcement_id=600b37abf0f93f0998523a35" class="btn button-small btn-success">Zobacz podgląd</a>
                                        
                                        
                                    
                                   
                                </div>
                               
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                        <div class="card">
                            <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/syberiancats/image/upload/v1611420488/shwkw1iv6my9ovarwv37.jpg" alt="zdjęcie ogłoszenia" class="card-img-top">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <div class="card-title">Karta SD 512GB</div>
                                <span class="badge text-light border border-success badge-mine">Moda i fitness v2</span>
                                
                                <p class="description">
                                    
                                        karta sd512gb
                                    
                                
                                </p>
                                <div>
                                    <p class="float-left author-city"> Glogow</p>
                                    <p class="float-right price"> 30zł</p>
                                </div>
                                <div style="clear: both;">
                                    
                                        
                                            <div class="dropdown">
                                                <button class="btn button-small btn-success dropdown-toggle justify-content-center" type="button" id="dropdownMenu" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                                    Modyfikacja
                                                </button>
                                                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu" style="background: #eeeeee">
                                                    <a href="/announcements/600c53484a60311d10533447/edit" class="dropdown-item">Edytuj</a>
                                                    <a href="/announcements/600c53484a60311d10533447/delete" class="dropdown-item">Usuń</a>
                                                    <a href="/announcements/600c53484a60311d10533447/add/picture" class="dropdown-item">Dodaj zdjęcie do galerii</a>
                                                    <a href="/announcements/600c53484a60311d10533447/edit/picture" class="dropdown-item">
                                                        Edytuj zdjęcie główne
                                                    </a>
                                                    <a href="/announcements/karta-sd-512gb?announcement_id=600c53484a60311d10533447" class="dropdown-item">Zobacz podgląd</a>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        
                                        
                                    
                                   
                                </div>
                               
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                
            </div>
        
       
   
</div>
<br>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center footer">
            <p>
                5zeta <script>document.write(new Date().getFullYear())</script>
                &copy; Wszelkie prawa zastrzeżone przez:
                <a href="https://mkdportfolio.pl">MK</a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```